# Running ASP.NET Core with HTTPS in docker from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, docker, https, azure-active-directory, .net-core

On my computer, I have installed Docker for Windows and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. I created a Web App with ASP.NET Core and configured Kestrel to use https. I tested if the application works without docker and it runs nicely over the https protocol. Next, I installed Visual Studio Tools for Docker and tried to debug the application in Docker. Although everything says that the application is running using https, I cannot connect to the application.

Since everything is working without docker, I would expect that it would work in Docker as well. Unfortunately I didn't find much about this topic regarding  .NET Core 1.0. Can someone point me in the right direction to set this up, so I can test this with https on Docker.

One thing I haven't mentioned yet, is that I require https to be able to use Azure Active Directory to authenticate and authorize my users.

I don't really know where to begin, so I have no code samples. But I can provide these upon request.

TIA

**Edit:** I logged into the container, installed Lynx and tested the web application. This works... The only thing I am not able to get solved is getting a connection from outside the container to the web application.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but I connect via my browser to the docker container over https. So on the host (the address I use in my browser) the port should 443 and the same port should be used by the application in the container. Basically forward the internal port 443 should be forwarded to the external port 443.

Comment: This is old, but if you still have the issue, can you post your `dockerfile` and the command you are using to run it?

Comment: I fixed it already... Paths in the configuration file had to be updated to linux format for paths. Besides that I built the images with the standard docker commands instead of using Docker Tools for VS2015. Now port 443 works. The next problem is to make Azure AD to work while using docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusting the paths in the configuration files to the linux format for paths and by using the standard docker commands to build the image worked. I guess the Docker Tools for VS2015 are not stable enough.

Comment: Could you write more details? With your comment I can't figure out how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It was actually really simple. The configured path in appsettings.json was a relative path and was created in the Windows format (e.g.: .\path\to\file). However the Docker image uses linux. Therefore the path should be in linux format: ./path/to/file. After changing that, everything started to work.

Comment: There are not a path in my appsettings.json. Where to change the path?

Comment: Sorry, I made the path configurable by putting it in appsettings.json myself and retrieve the variable in my code fro appsettings.json. The issue was not related to appsettings, but the way I was using paths in my code. This is also something specific for the linux image of dotnet core.

Comment: I'm using VS2017 and .net core 2.0 now. Could you make a simple solution then send to my email: xuanhoang.itdlu@gmail.com?
Thanks so much in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue with .Net Core Service for Windows Container. The issue was KestrelServerOptions.Listen method was passed with IPAddress.IPv6Loopback and IPAddress.Loopback. When I replaced them with IPAddress.Any, it started working.

After fix:

> WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
>                      .UseStartup()
>                      .UseKestrel(options => options.ConfigureEndpoints())
>                      .UseKestrel(options =>
>                      {
>                          options.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 443, 
>      listenOptions =>
>                          {
>                              listenOptions.UseHttps("pfx file path");
>                          });
>                      })
>                      .Build();

Comment: I put: options => options.ConfigureEndpoints() in my code then show error. Could you tell me which reference for this?

Comment: I created KestrelServerOptionsExtensions class something like [this](https://github.com/aspnet/samples/blob/master/samples/aspnetcore/security/KestrelHttps/KestrelServerOptionsExtensions.cs), and replaced the logic applied to find IPAddress with just IPAddress.Any, since IP Address will be dynamically assigned to docker instance. It started to work.